# Get Entrys relationships regardless of context

Tags: plugin-development, entries, matrix, relations

This might be a little complex, but here it goes:

**Goal:** For any given entry, determine where it's located. (Ex. Entry XYZ exists in a news entry, global field, single (page), etc...)

**Context:**
So far I figured I could go the custom SQL route until I learned more about craft internals, so what I did was create a Service that does the following query:

```
    $query = craft()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('element.*, detail.type, relation.fieldId AS sectionId, section.handle, section.name, section.hasUrls')
        ->from('elements_i18n AS element')
        ->join('relations AS relation', 'relation.sourceId = element.elementId')
        ->join('elements AS detail', 'detail.id = element.elementId')
        ->join('sections AS section', 'section.id = relation.fieldId AND section.hasUrls = 1')
        ->where('relation.targetId = :id', array(
            ':id' => $elementID
        ));

    $results = $query->queryAll();
    $results = MyPlugin_EntryRelationshipModel::populateModels($results);
```

I'm using `MyPlugin_EntryRelationshipModel` as a Facade and it extends `Craft\ElementCriteriaModel`

**Problem:** This works flawlessly until a Matrix field comes into play.

Answer (score 3):

So I found this: https://github.com/iainurquhart/craft_introvert which is exactly what I wanted to do. Hope this helps anyone else!

Comment: This one's a little bit more modern: https://github.com/boboldehampsink/reverserelations